# R307 Fingerprint Sensor working with more then 1000 fingerprints

Tags: algorithm, arduino, raspberry-pi, sensors

I want to integrate fingerprint sensor in my project. For the instance I have shortlisted [R307](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwizlpDWyuPuAhX-nUsFHTAcBlQYABAFGgJzZg&sig=AOD64_3SyFQNoR6XPEwwbuxCiCsA7k0V2A&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwi1iYnWyuPuAhUOU30KHa7BA2YQww8IugM&adurl=), which has capacity of 1000 fingerprints.But as project requirement is more then 1000 prints,so I will going to store print inside the host.

The procedure I understand by reading the [datasheet](https://www.electronicscomp.com/datasheet/r307-fingerprint-module-user-manual.pdf) for achieving project requirements is :

1. I will register the fingerprint by "GenImg".
2. I will download the template by "upchr"
3. Now whenever a fingerprint come I will follow the step 1 and step 2.
4. Then start some sort of matching algorithm that will match the recently downloaded template file with
   the template file stored in database.

So below are the points for which I want your thoughts

1. Is the procedure I have written above is correct and optimized ?
2. Is matching algorithm is straight forward like just comparing or it is some sort of tricky ? How can
   I implement that.Please suggest if some sort of library already exist.
3. The sensor stores the image in 256 * 288 pixels and if I take this file to host
   at maximum data rate it takes ~5(256 * 288*8/115200) seconds. which seems very
   large.

Thanks
Abhishek

PS: I just mentioned "HOST" from which I going to connect sensor, it can be Arduino/Pi or any other compute device depends on how much computing require for this task, I will select.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably figured it out yourself. But for anyone stumbling here in future.
You're correct for the most part.

- You will take finger image (`GenImg`)
- You will then generate a character file (`Img2Tz`) at `BufferID`: 1
- You'll repeat the above 2 steps again, but this time store the character file in `BufferID`: 2
- You're now supposed to generate a template file by combining those 2 character files (`RegModel`).
  The device combines them for you, and stores the template in both the character buffers
- As a last step; you need to store this template in your storage (`Store`)

For searching the finger: You'll take finger image once, generate a character file in BufferID : 1 and search the library (`Search`). This performs a linear search and returns the finger id along with confidence score.
There's also another method (`GR_Identify`); does all of the above automatically.

The question about optimization isn't applicable here, you're using a 3rd party device and you have to follow the working instructions whether it's optimized or not.

> The sensor stores the image in 256 * 288 pixels and if I take this file to host at maximum data rate it takes ~5(256 * 288*8/115200) seconds. which seems very large.

I don't really get what you mean by this, but the template file ( that you intend to upload to your host ) is 512 bytes, I don't think it should take much time.
If you want an overview of how this system is implemented; [Adafruit's Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library) is a good reference.